# Multiple threads access in java

Tags: java, arrays, multithreading

I have a 1000*1000 table and a few threads working on it. Each thread works independently on a certain part of the table and their "work" moves on the table with each iteration.

Instead of locking the whole table for a thread while the others are waiting, I would like to only lock only the needed cells for each thread.
So I am looking to lock the needed "block" of cells for each thread.

My idea is to create a lock table like : `Lock [][]gridLock=new Lock[1000][1000];` and lock the needed cells for each thread.

This would go along with a `gridlock(x,y,diameter)` and `gridUnlock(x,y,diameter)` methods to lock/unclock the needed cells.

Are there better ways to achieve this or is this method appropriate?

Comment: Of course it is possible but you should state a lot clearer what your threads are doing - why not let every thread operate on one row of the table and that is it, no need for any locking at all.

Comment: A million locks will probably become quite cumbersome.

Comment: Too broad. Elaborate on access pattern, access cost and what kind of data organization "table" has. Your text suggests *array* or *grid*, not table. Also very important is to determine the access types (read/write). Your 1 million locks approach will most likely perform so horribly that single threading would be faster. Not to mention its humongous deadlocking potential. Locking can possibly mostly avoided by just chosing more appropiate data structures. TL;DR: There are a lot of tools in the shed, but without knowing the problem no good choice can be made.

Comment: Yeah, rather confusing when you say that the threads work independently on _a certain part of the table_. Would you start by answering if "grid[m][n] be ever accessed by more than one thread"?

Answer (score 0):

Concurrent access on a single object is discouraged as this can create a large amount of problems. The biggest is the object can change state while the threads are working on it and this can disrupt the other threads.

If at all possible, I'd sugest each thread works on it own object, constructing the table piece by piece and once all the threads are finished, construct the final table. This will isolate all the threads and avoid unnecessary concurrency issues.

If the above method is not feasible. I'd try to keep the threads as independent as possible and isolate the table data as much as possible. Give each thread a set of rows in the table to work on, this will ensure that no threads modify the same parts of the table. Then each thread can go about modifying the cells in the rows it was assigned to.

Comment: The table object being `volatile` won't help much, since it applies only to the reference for the table, not its "cells".

Comment: @Kayaman I was suggesting the object be volatile as there is still the possibility of there being two objects inside the cpu memory which could be modified by different threads (or am I mistaken?), not because its cells are being modified by different threads.

Comment: There could be visibility issues, but that would mean very shoddy code. Provided that the table is made visible properly to all the threads, there is no need for (or advantage in using) `volatile`.

Comment: @Kayaman I wasn't aware of this. Thank you, I'll update the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks !
I don't know if the way i've deduced is correct but that's what i've done :

I have my lock matrix like : Lock[][]gridLock=new Lock[1000][1000].

But instead of initializing the whole 1millions lock in the beginning u_u, i do it only when needed like, something like :

```
public void lockAround(x, y, diameter){
[...] 
for{for{ //i and j <1000
    gridLock[i][j]=new ReentrantLock();
    gridLock[i][j].lock();
}}
}
```

And i set them to null when unlocked in the unlockAround(x,y,diameter) method.

Comment: This is incorrect as you have the same concurrency issues with the locks as you would have with the table.